# Detect all duplicates from second list based on the numbers in the first list

Tags: python

I have 2 lists, for example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
list2 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

I want to get a list 3 which will include all numbers from list2 matching the numbers from list1:

```
list3 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

I was trying to use 2 while loops to go through list1 and list2 and match numbers, but it gives me wrong number of values:

```
listO = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
listX = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
x_temp = []
a = 0
b = 0

while a < len(listO):
       while b < len(listX):
           if listO[a] == listX[b]:
               x_temp.append(listX[b])
               print("Outlier a:" , listO[a] )
               listX.remove(listX[b])
           b+=1
       b=0
       a+=1
```

list3 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]

Is there any way to do it using loops?

- Please do NOT provide solution using set() it doesn`t work for my lists!

Comment: Why sets don't work for your solution? `s1 = set(list1); list3 = [e for e in list2 if e in s1]`

Comment: This is a simplified problem. Original lists are unhashable.

Comment: From your example and expected result, there is no reason why converting list1 to a set wouldn't work. Please provide enough information so we can understand the constraint.

Comment: As I commented above, it is a simplified problem. The original program contains 4 multidimensional arrays (that is probably why sets do not work). Anyway, @orby `s solution is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a for loop:

```
listO = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
listX = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
x_temp = []

for x in listX:
    if x in listO:
        x_temp.append(x)

# [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension for this.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
list2 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]

list3 = [i for i in list2 if i in list1]
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: that is N^2. If the order is not critical then `set.intersect` is going to be amortized linear.